# ClassCastException:UIViewRoot cannot be cast to org.portletfaces.bridge.component.PortletNamingContainerUIViewRoot

Tags: jsf-2, portlet

For a simple jsf 2.0 and Tomcat 7  application I am getting following error:

> Casting Error java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot cannot be cast to
>   org.portletfaces.bridge.component.PortletNamingContainerUIViewRoot

```
  Aug 24, 2012 11:55:40 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy       handleRenderException
 SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/hello.xhtml]
 java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot cannot be cast to   org.portletfaces.bridge.component.PortletNamingContainerUIViewRoot
at   org.portletfaces.bridge.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:62)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:823)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1611)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
at   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrateg       y.java:380)
```

hello.xhtml is as follows:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:body>

    <h:form>
       <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. But once h:head or h:body is removed, page loads ok, except for javascripts and css, which require h:head. These will not be loaded.